# Does my sql code go unavailable when I upgrade my SQL Server from 2008 to 2014?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2014

I have a server running SQL Server 2008 Enterprise version which has a lot of SQL Codes and I want to upgrade it into SQL Server 2014 Enterprise version. But I don't know what will happen after I upgrade the SQL Server. Will there any SQL Code go unavailable/error? Will it run correctly after upgrading?

Comment: SQL Code, which is plain SQL Code will be runable on your new server. What i would worry about is access rights, configuration of database and server (collations, etc..), logins, files, filegroups, linked servers, agent jobs... When migrating from one server to another my problem was never in SQL Code ;-)

Comment: Please be more concete in your question. Are you using special features? Take a look into MSDN to view any breaking changes between different SQL server versions..

Comment: I recommend to have a look at Irina Tudose's Blog - Very nice "Checklist" imho: http://yrushka.com/index.php/sql-server/database-recovery/sql-server-migration-from-one-server-to-another-detailed-checklist/

Answer (score 1):

`SQL Server 2008/2014` is a tool. It has got nothing to do with data/procedures/views etc. Data for SQL Server is stored in the form of .mdf files. So, no, your data or procedurers wont be touched. But yes lot of features are going to be deprecated in SQL Server 2014 when compared to SQL Server 2008. Full list is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx). You should go through the list and find a suitable replacement for every deprecated item before migrating.